# Identify text in cell to return value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify if a cell contains a certain string of text to return a value in another cell on the same row.

I get a mismatch error.

```vb
Sub iflocate_school1()

Dim MailValue As String
Dim EcoleValue As String

MailValue = Range("C7:C725").Value

EcoleValue = Range("E7:E725").Value

If MailValue Like "Cambridge.ac" Then
EcoleValue = "Cambridge"

ElseIf MailValue Like "imperial" Then
EcoleValue = "Imperial"

ElseIf MailValue Like "oxford" Then
EcoleValue = "Oxford"

ElseIf MailValue Like "lse" Then
EcoleValue = "LSE"

ElseIf MailValue Like "york" Then
EcoleValue = "York"

Else EcoleValue = " "

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: MailValue will be a 2D array not a string as will EcoleValue. You are reading a multi-cell range from the sheet. Are those ranges merged cells? If yes, take the top left cell of the range instead.

Comment: the main error I see is that you cannot store a range array of values into a string variable. You have to use range object, set range object, and then loop through each cell in range.

Comment: ^^ ah. That would explain the multi-cell range

Comment: In addition, it seems like the if statement check, all it is doing is capitalizing the first word. if you end up having hundreds of else ifs, might as well just create a function combining UCASE(string) and LEFT(string,1) to return a string with only the first letter capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check script below. Note that the script assumes you are working on sheets(1) of your current activeworkbook.

You were getting a mismatch error:

```
"A VBA Type Mismatch Error occurs when you try to assign a value between two 
different variable types"
```

As I mentioned on the comment section, the error you were getting was due to storing a range array of values into a string varible.

The code below stores range ("C7:C725") into a range object (from your example above), and then I used the if statement you created to do a loop to each cell in range ("C7:C725").

The if statement results will appear is the next column cel, (offset(0,1)) so range("D7:D725"). Change offset to (0,2) if you want the results to show on col ("E7:E725").

Please use code below:

```
Sub foo()

Dim wb As Workbook

'dim range object, instead of a string variable
Dim mailvalue As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'setting the range("C7:C725") into the dim range (mailvalue) created above
'change the sheet number or the range as you need
Set mailvalue = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C7:C725")

    For Each cel In mailvalue
    
        'all the if statement result will show in the next column (col D) of cel being iterated (cel.offset(0,1) where .offset(row,col))
        'change the offset as needed, on your script above seems like you want output in column E, so I would change from offset(0,1) to offset(0,2).
        If cel.Value Like "Cambridge.ac" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Cambridge"
    
        ElseIf cel.Value Like "imperial" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Imperial"
    
        ElseIf cel.Value Like "oxford" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Oxford"
    
        ElseIf cel.Value Like "lse" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "LSE"
    
        ElseIf cel.Value Like "york" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "York"
    
        Else
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = " "

        End If

    Next cel


End Sub
```

Lastly, your if statement looks like all it does is capitalize the first letter. The " Else If" list can grow to hundreds. It is possible to remove the whole if statement portion if you just created a function that capitalizes the first letter of a string.

You can add a function that capitalizes the first letter:

```
Function capstr(s As String) As String

Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String

    s1 = UCase(Left(s, 1))
    s2 = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)

    capstr = s1 + s2

End Function
```

and reduce your code to this:

```
Sub foo()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim mailvalue As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set mailvalue = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C7:C725")

    For Each cel In mailvalue

        If cel.Value <> "" Then

            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = capstr(cel.Value)

        Else

            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""

        End if
    
    Next cel


End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @victor song, 

Thank you very much for your help. 

I tried the code that you mentioned, and while the mismatch error has now disappeared, the code does not appear to be executing. 

I will try to figure out what is happening - the problem resides surely in an error that I made while adapting the code. 

In any case, thank you once more and have a good day!

Comment: if you want to go over it let me know. as one of the users said. Try using  F8 to execute the script step-by-step, and see if you can troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

Read the comments and adjust the code to fit your needs

```
Public Sub iflocate_school1()

    Dim mailRange As Range
    Dim mailCell As Range
    
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim mailRangeAddress As String
    
    Dim valuesToReplace(4) As Variant ' Set the (4) to the number of items you want to replace minus 1 as array index is base 0
    
    
    ' Adjust these values to fit your needs
    
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    mailRangeAddress = "C7:C725"
    
    valuesToReplace(0) = Array("Cambridge.ac", "Cambridge")
    valuesToReplace(1) = Array("imperial", "Imperial")
    valuesToReplace(2) = Array("oxford", "Oxford")
    valuesToReplace(3) = Array("lse", "LSE")
    valuesToReplace(4) = Array("york", "York")
    
    
    Set mailRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range(mailRangeAddress)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in range
    For Each mailCell In mailRange
    
        ' Check if cell has any of the values
        Dim counter As Integer
        For counter = 0 To UBound(valuesToReplace)
            
            Dim replaceValue As String
            ' This -> valuesToReplace(counter)(0) is the first value of the first item (when counter = 0)
            If InStr(mailCell.value, valuesToReplace(counter)(0)) > 0 Then
                
                ' This -> valuesToReplace(counter)(1) is the second value of the first item (when counter = 0)
                replaceValue = valuesToReplace(counter)(1)
                
            End If
            
            mailCell.Offset(0, 2).value = replaceValue
        
        Next counter
    
    Next mailCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @ricardo diaz, 

Thank you very much for your help. 

I tried the code, and now see a "subscript out of range" error. 

It must surely be due to an error made while trying to adjust the code you shared to my case. Am working now on figuring out the mistake (I am a complete novice in this)

In any case, thank you once more and have a good day

Comment: Try stepping into the code using `F8` key and check what line is causing the error. Come back and report so I can give you a hand

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively I think you could to a iteration through the rows.

I think the issue might be that the Like command returns a value.

Try:

```
If MailValue Like "Cambridge.ac" = "True" Then EcoleValue = "Cambridge"
```

Also, if you change lines int he code the underscore key is like the return. i.e,

```
If MailValue Like "Cambridge.ac" = "True" _ 
Then EcoleValue = "Cambridge"
```

Alternatively I think you could to a iteration through the rows.

```
Dim i as integer
i=7
Do while Cells(i,3) <> ""
 If instr((cells,i),"Cambridge.ac") >0 then Cells(i,4) = "Cambridge"
 If instr((cells,i),"imperial") >0 then Cells(i,4) = "imperial"
Loop
```

I am not sure about using the ranges I might not be that advanced.

Comment: Hello @L DeFramce, 

Thank you very much for your help. 

I did try modifying the Like command to include a "True" verification like you indicated. Am still working on getting a result (as indicated in my messages above)

Hopefully I will be able to figure this out soon! 

In any case, thank you once more and have a good day